# Batch script restricting duplicate copies

Tags: batch-file, copy

I made a script that makes 4 folders Images, Documents, Programs and Other. The script looks into selected directory and copies the files accordingly to the folders, but my problem is how to restrict the files that are copied to the specified folders to not copy into "Other" folder also?

Here is the part of the script:

```
:run1

mkdir %var2%\%1\Images

copy "%var%\*.jpg" "%var2%\%1\Images" 

mkdir %var2%\%1\Documents

copy "%var%\*.docx" "%var2%\%1\Documents" 

mkdir %var2%\%1\Programs

copy "%var%\*.exe" "%var2%\%1\Programs" 

mkdir %var2%\%1\Other

copy "%var%" "%var2%\%1\Other" 

goto complete
```

Comment: What do you want to copy into the `Other` folder?

Comment: other files that are left over, that do no fit the category of the Images, Documents and Programs folders

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing should work:

```
:run1

pushd "%var2%"

for %%a in (Images Documents Programs Other) do mkdir "%~1\%%~a" 2>nul

for %%a in (jpg png bmp tif gif) do (
   copy "*.%%a" "%~1\Images"
   attrib +h "*.%%a"
)

for %%a in (doc docx txt pdf) do (
   copy "*.%%a" "%~1\Documents"
   attrib +h "*.%%a"
)

for %%a in (exe com bat cmd) do (
   copy "*.%%a" "%~1\Programs"
   attrib +h "*.%%a"
)

   copy "*.*" "%~1\Other"
   attrib -h "*.*"

popd
goto complete
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of tasks (and the backup processes) was the reason for the creation of the archive attribute of files.

```
:run1

    attrib +a "%var%\*"

    xcopy /i /m "%var%\*.jpg"   "%var2%\%1\Images" 
    xcopy /i /m "%var%\*.docx"  "%var2%\%1\Documents" 
    xcopy /i /m "%var%\*.exe"   "%var2%\%1\Programs" 
    xcopy /i /m "%var%\*"       "%var2%\%1\Other" 

goto complete
```

The `attrib +a` will set the archive attribute. The `/i` switch of xcopy will handle directory creation and the `/m` is asking xcopy to only copy files with the archive attribute set and, when the file is copied, remove the attribute. That way, the last command will only copy files that were not copied.