# Batch script moving multiple files

Tags: batch-file, move

I am trying to move multiple files with different(specific) extensions to another directory by using the following:

move "%var2%\%1\Other*.docx" "%var2%\%1\Documents"

The problem i am having is adding another file, for example .txt. I want to move different files but i cannot figure out how to add more than one extension.

Comment: Why not add one line per extension? :)

Comment: ha, that is true, so simple yet i didnt think of it, thanks. Still i wonder if there is also another way of doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch script restricting duplicate copies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170821/batch-script-restricting-duplicate-copies)

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
@echo off
set $ext=.doc .txt .bat
for %%a in (%$ext%) do move "%var2%\%1\Other\*%%a" "%var2%\%1\Documents"
```